App crashed with ClassNotFound exception: androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView when updating compose BOM from 2023.10.01 to any of the latest
App crashes on opening any compose screen when updating to any compose BOM higher than 2023.10.01 which was the last working one
Stack trace:
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView;
                                                                                                         at androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt.setContent(ComponentActivity.kt:55)
                                                                                                         at androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt.setContent$default(ComponentActivity.kt:51)


Used individual version numbers for the compose libraries used crash was still noticed

Can you share your build.gradle files?

You probably have some compose dependency that still uses an explcit (now incompatible) version number instead of letting the bom handle it.

Crash gone with update to latest BOM 2024.05.00

The same for me.. I run Appium UIAutomator tests against the app that has the dependencies for https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping update : "2024.05.00"...  but app crashes while running autotests... and it doesn't crash manually
